# How do we solve the system of trigonometry equations?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I am unable to solve the following system of trig equations. My intention is to find the values of $x$ and $x_o$.

$$6\cdot \sin(x) = 8\cdot \sin(x_o)$$

$$6\cdot \cos(x) + 8\cdot \cos(x_o) = 10$$

Here's what I have tried so far:

Multiplied the both sides of $[1]$ by $cos(x)$, and $sin(x)$ to $[2]$.

$$6\cdot \sin(x) \cdot \cos(x) = 8\cdot \sin(x_o) \cdot \cos(x)$$
$$6\cdot \cos(x) \cdot \sin(x) + 8\cdot \cos(x_o) \cdot \sin(x) = 10 \cdot \sin(x)$$

Subtracted $[1]$ from $[2]$.

$$ 8\cdot \cos(x_o) \cdot \sin(x) = 10 \cdot \sin(x) -8\cdot \sin(x_o) \cdot \cos(x) $$

$$ \sin(x)(4\cdot \cos(x_o) - 5)  = -4\cdot \sin(x_o) \cdot \cos(x) $$
$$ \tan(x)(4\cdot \cos(x_o) - 5)  = -4\cdot \sin(x_o) $$

And this is where I am currently stuck on.

I would be appreciated if you could help me with solving the values for the variables.

Comment: Formatting tip:  your posts will look nicer and be easier to read if you use `\sin`, `\log` and so on for the standard functions.

Comment: I would take the $x$ terms to the LHS, the $x_0$ terms to the RHS, square and add and the value of $\cos x_0$ should drop out.

Comment: Thanks @saulspatz.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll write $y$ instead of $x_0$ to cut down on typos.

$$\begin{align}
3\sin x&=4\sin y\\
3\cos x &= 5 -4\cos y
\end{align}$$
Square both sides of each equation and add the results:
$$\begin{align}
9\sin^2x&=16\sin^2y\\
9\cos^2x&=25-40\cos y+16\cos^2y\\
9&=25-40\cos y+16
\end{align}$$
which gives $$\begin{align}
\cos y &= \frac45\\
\sin y &= \pm\frac35\\
\sin x&= \frac43\sin y=\pm\frac45\\
\cos x&=\frac13(5-4\cos y)=\frac35
\end{align}$$

Take it from here.

Comment: Thanks a lot @saulspatz.